# I have a numpy.ndarray, why does the shape return a tuple

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray that is (10L,). I understand that (,) in python means tuple, but when I ask the type of the object, it returns that it is a numpy.ndarray. Why is that? So, I thought I had a 10 X 1 Matrix, but now I feel maybe it is like a list??

Input:

```
 type(summary_data)
```

Output:

```
 numpy.ndarray
```

Input:

```
summary_data.shape
```

Output:

```
(10L,)
```

Input:

```
summary_data.shape[0]
```

Output:

```
10L
```

Input:

```
summary_data.shape[1]
```

Output:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'` is the output I get when I run that

Comment: I had a typo, it is `list(summary_data.shape)`

Comment: Why do you need a list?  What's wrong with shape being a tuple?

Comment: Is this question really about shape being a tuple, or about your array not being 2d?

Comment: "but when I ask the type of the object, it returns that it is a numpy.ndarray. Why is that?" Because the type of the object is an `numpy.ndarray`, the type of the object returned by `numpy.ndarray.shape` is `tuple`. IOW: `summary_data is not summary_data.shape` It returns a `tuple` because a `tuple` is a reasonable data-structure to hold the shape. It is documented as such. I am not sure exactly what you are asking.